# my export from oracle sql dev to excel fails after 10%

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

My machine is running windows 2019; my oracle sql dev is 19.2.1.247.

I have run a query and the result is 330k+ rows, but when i try to export it to excel, it stops after 10% complete. no error message provided.

If i try the same thing in oracle sql dev 4.0.2.15, all rows are exported

Comment: I'm not sure you expect us to be able to tell what's happening. Have you looked for any log files generated by SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.

Remove your date columns from the export and it'll work.

Even better, upgrade to version 19.4 or 20.2 where the bug has been fixed.